# Handle lower iOS version segment control

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I want the segment control in lower iOS versions to look like iOS 13 segment control.
I want to apply theme of latest segment control on iOS 11. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

The segment control on iOS 11 looks like

[image]

The segment control on iOS 13 looks like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No way to achieve this , the new segment look is encapsulated with the new IOS version , you can make a custom segment to look exactly as you need in all versions